# Prolog: Program that returns a list of lessons after it reads a certain number

Tags: prolog

Hello so i have been stuck with the a small program in prolog.

I have a small knowledge base and i am trying to print a list for example of the lessons that a student like if the X i read from the user is 1.

```
collect_results:-

read(X),

read(Y),

\+(X>5),

\+(X<1),

X =:= 1:-
setof(Z,kb(Y,K,Z)^kb(Y,K,Z),L).
```

This is the code i have tried to make.

The Y is the person I want to print the list for.
It might take names like Mike and then i want to print the lessons mike likes for example.

I would like to add more options later on if the X is equal to 2 for example to print something else and so on. Any tips on how to do it correctly would be appreciated.

Comment: Side comment: No: `\+(X>5)`, yes: `X =< 5`. No: `\+(X<1)`, yes: `X >= 1`.

Comment: No: `..., X =:= 1:- ...`.  It's unclear what you're trying to do with this. `:-` is for defining a predicate represented by the term on the left. But you're using it in the middle of a predicate clause definition. You must be getting some error messages from your code that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Start with `collect_result(X,Y)` and skip the `read/1`. Why do you have two `kb/3` calls in `setof/3`? Where does `K` come from? Okay, `collect_result(X,Y,K,L)` then.

Comment: Yeah @lurker I dint notice i am getting an error operator expected after expression.

Comment: @Tomas By I am being asked to make collect_results/0 sorry i didnt mention both of these things.

Comment: Yes, you're getting errors due to the improper use of `:-`.

Comment: @lurker What i am trying to do is print the list if the x is equal to 1 but i am really bad at prolog.

Comment: Note that I said "start with". You can call `read/1` before you call `collect_result/?`, or you can change it later.

Comment: The operator you should use instead of `:-` is `->`, and then you also need to handle the case when it is not true.